# How to store array values into a new array (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, random

Issue: I've completed steps 1-4 of this assignment. However, I'm currently stuck on steps 5 and 6 of this assignment, so I'm at a loss on how to combine my fizz and buzz String arrays into a separate fizzbuzz String array.

TL;DR I don't know how to do steps five and six.

Assignment:

> You can do this all in the main method. This is using a game called
>   Fizz-Buzz, an ancient programmer’s game.
>
> 1. Start by initializing some variables to set the maximum and minimum value of a random number and for the capacity of an array.
>      (20/100)
> 2. Initialize three new arrays, one for a list of random numbers (as integers) and two for String arrays called ‘fizz’ and
>      ‘buzz’.(20/100)
> 3. You’ll also need an integer for counting.
> 4. Write a for loop that generates a random number for each position in the array. Remember that the range for this will be set by
>      the two variables initialized at the beginning of the file. There are
>      multiple ways to create a random number, just find one that works for
>      you. (20/100)
> 5. Using the count of the arrays, create another array that will store all of the fizzes and buzzes without any extra space leftover in
>      the array. (20/100)
> 6. Use a for each loop to iterate the array and print all of the fizzes and buzzes, with no other output. (20/100)

What I've accomplished thus far:

```
            /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class FizzBuzz {

  //2a. Initialize one int array for a list of random numbers.
  private static int[] anArray;
  private static final int size = 10;

  //2b. Initialize two String arrays called 'fizz' and 'buzz.'
  public static String[] fizz;
  public static String[] buzz;
  public static String[] fizzbuzz;
  public static Random rand = new Random();

  //1. Set the maximum and minimum value of a random number.
  private static final int min = 0;
  private static final int max = 5;
  private static int count = 0;

  public static int[] list() {

    anArray = new int[size];
    //3. Make an integer for counting("counter" in the for loop)
    //4. Write a for loop that generates a random number for
    //   each position in the array.
    for(count = 0; count < anArray.length; count++) {
      anArray[count] = randomFill();
    }
    return anArray;
  }

  public static void print() {

    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(anArray[i] + ": " + fizz[i] + buzz[i]);
    }
  }

  public static int randomFill() {  
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  }

  public static String[] getF() {

    fizz = new String[size];

    int x = 0;
    int counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < fizz.length; counter++) {
      if(anArray[counter] % 3 == 0) {
      fizz[counter] = "fizz";
    } else {
        fizz[counter] = "";
      }
  }
    return fizz; 
  }
  public static String[] getB() {
    buzz = new String[size];

    int x = 0;
    int counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < buzz.length; counter++) {

      if(anArray[counter] % 5 == 0) {
      buzz[counter] = "buzz";
    } else {
        buzz[counter] = "";
      }
  } 
    return buzz;
  }

  public static String[] getFB() {
    fizzbuzz = new String[size];


    return fizzbuzz;
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    list();
    getF();
    getB();
    print();
  } 
}
```

Comment: you never call `GetFizzOrBuzz()`. So you never assign any values to `fizzbuzz`. This code won't work at all, since `fizzbuzz` is never initialized. You can/should try to reproduce this result with a debugger (there should be one built in to whatever IDE you're using).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Paul Hey, thanks for the input. I realized that immediately after I posted the question, and edited the post to reflect me calling GetFizzOrBuzz()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

### How `Random` works

Your implementation of `Random` won't quite work for simple reason:
If you call the default-constructor, the seed of the PRNG will be the current time, thus you're quite likely starting multiple PRNGs with the same seed and thus receive the same random-value multiple times. Use a single `Random`-instance instead:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

public static int randomFill() {
    return rnd.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) should help in understanding the issue better.

### General implementation

Try to stick as close to the given task as possible. E.g. the problem explicitly states that you should use a variable to specify the length of the arrays, while you're using a fixed magic-number. The task explicitly states to use two arrays `fizz` and `buzz`, you're using one array called `fizzbuzz`.

Inside `GetFizzBuff`, you probably meant `x = 2;` instead of `x = x + 2;`. Apart from that this part is fine.

### Output

As above: try to stick to the given task. It's explicitly stated to only output the fizzes and buzzes, not any integers. Or at least try to print a value and the corresponding fizzes and buzzes in the same line, to produce readable output.